Building mvn sources jar during package or deploy
trying to build my project with the sources jar included. The build works and generates the jar file, but no sources.jar file is in my .m2 directory. I've been running 'mvn clean install'
Here's my pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pick.box</groupId>
  <artifactId>pick-box</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>

  <name>pick-box</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>


  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>github</id>
      <name>GitHub wbf22 Apache Maven Packages</name>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/wbf22/PickBox</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.10.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
      <!-- run mvn source:jar to generate these in /target -->
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>


      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>


Running 'mvn source:jar' I do get the sources.jar file in my target directory. So I think the plugin is somehow being ignored during clean install. Any ideas?
Thanks

Chatgpt helped me find the solution. Looks like I was doing this in the pluginManagement section of the pom. need to do it under build > plugins instead. Here's the updated pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pick.box</groupId>
  <artifactId>pick-box</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>

  <name>pick-box</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>


  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>github</id>
      <name>GitHub wbf22 Apache Maven Packages</name>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/wbf22/PickBox</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.10.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- run mvn source:jar to generate these in /target -->
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>


    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>


You should define the version as in the original post via pluginManagement and make the binding to the life cycle as given here but without the version and use the other goal (jar-no-fork)...
